# How to map this in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I need help transforming a 3 columns df into an array 3x3. See picture attached (Pandas mapping). Thanks in advance.

[Pandas mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch74M.png)

Comment: Displays image instead of a link + small formatting with backticks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Vlad's comment means I shouldn't be answering this but:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2', 'C3', 'C3', 'C3'],
                   'b':[0.00, 0.20, 0.10, 0.30, 0.00, 0.10, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
                   'c':['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3']})

df.pivot(index='c', columns='a')
```

Comment: Indeed that's what it means.